# Edit row on a new page

Tags: phpmyadmin, row, edit

a few months ago, we were able to open "edit row" on a new page, but now it doesn't work anymore.

Is there a way to do it again? 
When I do a big search and to edit 1 row, I don't want to doing my search again after saving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [feature request](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13890) in the tracker about this, I suggest you add a comment there.

Comment: Thanks, I did post